# Image Trace in Adobe Illustrator CC - Colors are inverted

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH86TapncZQ) on how to create Digital Version of a signature. In the Video he clicks on Trace Options, and then clicks Ignore white, before doing a a Live Trace to vectorize the signature. When I try to emulate his process in the newest form of Illustrator, the resulting image, before vectorization is changed to reverse type (white text against black background) as opposed to the original scheme. Is there  a way to toggle the reversal of colors or I am inadvertently setting an option in Image Trace that is doing this?

THanks!

Comment: Are you tracing a gif image??

Comment: @Scott I am tracing a .pdf

Comment: A PDF? Did you try simply opening the PDF with Illustrator or did you "place" the PDF? It may already be vector, opening rather than placing would show you. -- Overall point is if the tracing colors are odd, it's most likely due to the image format you are tracing. You can always expand after the trace and change fill colors.